# Discord.py client.commands send mentioned user

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have this command called `p!slap` and I want it so that my bot will say `{message.author} slapped {message.mention}` and a random gif but I have no idea how to. Can anyone help? Thanks!

````py
@client.command()
async def slap(ctx, message.mention):
  embedVar = discord.embed(title=f"<@{message.author.id}> slapped {message.mention}")
  list = [
          #gif links and stuff
        ]
  await ctx.channel.send(random.choice(list))```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a few problems.

- At first, I couldn't understand what you're trying to do with naming a parameter `message.mention` but I guess what you're trying to do is "slapping" the person you mentioned in command. For that, you have to get the member object in parameter. Then, you can mention this member.
- Also, you shouldn't define a variable named `list`. This might cause a error because of the built-in method [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list).
- An another thing is, there's no `embed` method for discord module, it must be `discord.Embed`. You have to pay attention to the uppercase letters.
- You never sent the embed you defined, you must send it for your command to work.
- For the last one, I don't know what'll be in the list `lst` but I guess there will be files. If you're going to send a file, you cannot just send it. You have to pass a parameter in [`.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.send) method. But this is only for the files. If you're just going to send a link, then you don't have to pass any parameters.

```py
@client.command()
async def slap(ctx, member: discord.Member):
  embedVar = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author.mention} slapped {member.mention}")
  lst = [
          #gif links and stuff
        ]
  await ctx.channel.send(file=discord.File(random.choice(lst)), embed=embedVar)
```

Comment: TYSMMMM i fixed all that but it wont send anything for some reason

Comment: Is there any error? Can you edit your answer with the real list of "**gif links and stuff**"?

Comment: Yep I added the gif links and stuff. No errors. as if it weren't even a command lol

Comment: Do you have a `on_command_error` event? It might be blocking you to seeing the errors.

Comment: Nope I didnt see anything

Comment: Then there is no reason for the command not to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227302/discussion-between-nicholas-chen-and-nurqm).